# Is there a way to refer to a later defined struct (either by prototyping or else)?

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to use `struct` for defining in a centralized way how xml nodes are defined that I want to read by my code.

This currently looks like this:

```
    const struct sXmlRootDefinition
    {
        const char* name = "case";
        const char* parents[1] = { "none" };
    } sRootDefinition;

    //--------------------
    // LEVEL 1 nodes
    //--------------------

    const struct sXmlCaseDefDefinition
    {
        const char* name = "case_definition";
        const char* parents[1] = { sRootDefinition.name };
    } sCaseDefDefinition;
```

In the second struct I have the member `parents` that indicate that this node is child to the node managed by `sXmlRootDefinition struct`.
I really would like to also implement a `child` member. For `sXmlRootDefinition` this should for instance look like:
`const char* childs[1] = { sCaseDefDefinition.name };`

As `sCaseDefDefinitio` is defined later this obviously will fail and it does fail. Of course I could reverse the order but then I run into trouble with the `parent` member.

Trying to prototype the later defined `struct`: Either it doesn't work or I am using wrong syntax.

Is there a way do achieve what I would like to achieve and if so how can I approach this?

---

EDIT:

This is what I tried:

```
    struct sXmlCaseDefDefinition
    {
        const char* name;
        const char* parents[1];
    } sCaseDefDefinition;

    const struct sXmlRootDefinition
    {
        const char* name = "case";
        const char* parents[1] = { "none" };
        const char* childs[1] = { sCaseDefDefinition.name };
    } sRootDefinition;

    //--------------------
    // LEVEL 1 nodes
    //--------------------

    sCaseDefDefinition.name = "case_definition";
    sCaseDefDefinition.parents[0] = sRootDefinition.name;
```

It is not working.

Comment: Don’t use identifier prefixes such as `s`. They don’t serve a useful purpose (especially when used inconsistently as in your example) and are a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Can you point out where I have been inconsistent? ```s``` as a prefix is indicating that struct name or an instantiation is a ```struct```. I use ```t``` for classes ans ```e``` for ```enum```. But as I am a C++ learner I am very happy if I can learn on how to properly define names etc.

Comment: A simple solution would be to define a const variable for the common name, and then have both structs refer to that. rather than both of them try to get it from the other

Comment: @ManyQuestions The inconsistency is having the same prefix for different things (structs and instances of structs, here). Anyway, the point is that neither of these conveys any useful information. A `struct` isn’t usefully different from an `enum` or  a `class` (in fact, in  C++ in particular, `struct` and `class` are *identical* except for default visibility rules).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Thanks for the explanation. I understand your arguments. My thinking was that if I name my variables with a specific letter I can more easily see, if it is a struct, an enum or class. But I will follow your advice.

Comment: “I can more easily see, if it is a struct, an enum or class” — Yes, but why? My point is that this information is simply *not useful* in actual programs. On the contrary: if you think the information is useful there’s probably something wrong with the code, because this distinction shouldn’t matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a proper constructor, and maybe use the standard library for strings and dynamic arrays:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct XmlRootDefinition
{
    std::string name = "case";
    std::string parent = "none";
    std::vector<std::string> children;
};

struct XmlCaseDefDefinition
{
    XmlCaseDefDefinition(XmlRootDefinition& parent) :
      parent(parent.name)
    {
        parent.children.push_back(this->name);
    }

    std::string name = "case_definition";
    std::string parent;
};

XmlRootDefinition rootDefinition;
const XmlCaseDefDefinition caseDefDefinition(rootDefinition);
```

Comment: thank you very much. Your code looks good and does what I want to. Any advice on how to make this work when I have a super-struct that binds an XmlCaseDefDefinition instance and a XmlRootDefinition instance together? I tried this but didn't get it to work.

Comment: You can still do that in the superstruct constructor. `struct Superstruct { XmlRootDefinition rd; XmlCaseDefDefinition cdd; Superstruct() : rd(), cdd(this->rd) { } }; `

Answer (score 0):

You can do a forward declaration:

i.E.:

```
struct MyStruct;
```

After this you can use it, as long as you don't dereference it, or declare a member, which requires the size to be known.

So this would be ok because the size of the struct doesn't need to be known:

```
void MyFunc(struct MyStruct *ptr);

void MyFunc()
{
    struct MyStruct *ms;
}
```

However, if you write a function that needs to know the size, it will require the full definition:

```
void MyFunc()
{
    // size is unknown here.
    struct MyStruct ms;
}
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. In my first struct I need to access the member of the second struct. I've tried to define the second struct before the first with its member but without putting values to them and filling the members after declaration of first struct but it is just a mess. Please see Edit above to see what I've tried.